# Are there any restrictions on access to browser extensions storage?

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions, browser-extension, webextension-storage

I'm trying to understand security implications of using browser extensions `storage`. A few things are not clear to me when I read the [WebExtensions storage documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage).

Documentation says among others that:

> Values are scoped to the extension, not to a specific domain (i.e. the same set of key/value pairs are available to all scripts in the background context and content scripts).

also:

> Each extension has its own storage area, which can be split into different types of storage.

also:

> The storage area is not encrypted and shouldn't be used for storing confidential user information.

Considering the above I still have a few questions here:

1. Is it possible for extension E to access data stored by extension A?
2. Is it possible for an arbitrary webpage to access data stored by extension A?
3. Is it possible for a webpage on which extension A is run to access data stored by this extension?

I read a few bits about `localStorage` (in)security but I'm not sure if and how those rules apply to

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note:** `storage.local` (e,g. `browser.storage.local.get('item')` or `chrome.storage.local.get('item'))` is a WebExtension API and limited to the extension. It should not be confused with `Window.localStorage` (e.g. `localStorage.getItem('item')`) which is a Web API and not secure and accessible.

### In case of `storage.local`:

> Is it possible for extension E to access data stored by extension A?

No. Each extension has its own `storage.local` area and not accessible by other extensions.

> Is it possible for an arbitrary webpage to access data stored by
>   extension A?

No. As above access is limited to the extension only.

> Is it possible for a webpage on which extension A is run to access
>   data stored by this extension?

No. As above.

Comment: Thanks erosman for the answer and the clarifying note :) FTR I'm aware of the difference you mention and my problem was exactly that `localStorage` (Web API) security is extensively covered here and there but I had a really hard time to find similar details about `storage` (WebExtension API) security. Thanks for clarifying this for me.